# SQL COUNT of zero values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am calculating how many zeros appear in a series of columns based on a ID.

Example Table:

```
ID     hour1      hour2      hour3 
 1     2          10         0
 2     0          0          0
 3     0          24         0
```

I think it would look something like this, but obviously it doesn't work

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(CASE WHEN(  
FROM (VALUES (hour1) , (hour2) , (hour3)) 
AS VALUE (v)) AS ZERO_HOURS
```

Desired output:

```
ID     ZERO_HOURS      
 1     1                  
 2     3                 
 3     2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.id, h.num_zeros
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as num_zeros
      from (values (hour1), (hour2), (hour3)) v(h)
      where h = 0
     ) h;
```

Of course a `case` expression is not so hard either:

```
select t.id,
       (case when hour1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end +
        case when hour2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end
        case when hour3 = 0 then 1 else 0 end
       ) as num_zeros
```

Or, if there are no negative or `NULL` values:

```
select t.id,
       (1 - sign(hour1)) + (1 - sign(hour2)) + (1 - sign(hour3)) as num_zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, hour1 INT, hour2 INT, hour3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (hour1, hour2, hour3) VALUES
(2, 10, 0),
(0, 0 , 0),
(0, 24, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
   , c.value('count(/root/*[./text()="0"])','INT') AS ZERO_HOURS
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT hour1, hour2, hour3
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+
| ID | ZERO_HOURS |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          1 |
|  2 |          3 |
|  3 |          2 |
+----+------------+
```